# MySQL stored procedure query become case sensitive but simple query returns results without case sensitive

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures

I am using AWS MySQL database and have issue in stored procedure.
When I run below query it gives me perfect result, but when i put the same query in stored procedure it returns Null result just because my search keyword is in small letters and table data in capital.

this is my query

```
select * from product where product_name like concat(in_search_keyword,'%');
```

In table product name is e.g "One Plus 6T" and when i pass 'one' in in_search_keyword it gives me null, at the same time when i run this simple query without SP it gives me 1 row.

I have tried solution like changing collation to utf8_general_ci but it didn't work.

My collations are like this

collation_connection : utf8mb4_general_ci

collation_database : utf8_general_ci

collation_server : latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: Where are you changing the collation? Collation can be set on a server-wide basis, the database itself, individual columns, as a modifier in a query predicate and on a per-connection basis too. I'm assuming it's one of those.

Comment: yes, I have changed collation of database and tables, and also for product_name column too.

Comment: What about your Connection's collation? That might explain why a sproc (which might not inherit a connection's collation settings) behaves differently to executing the query directly.

Comment: Using a `ci`-collation is the correct approach. If it does not work, you seem to have made a mistake in setting it. Can you add the table definition? (the output of `show create table product`). You can remove all columns and indexes that are not relevant here, important are the column `product_name` and the stuff at the end, both of which can contain collation/charset definitions.

Comment: @Dai I have added collation for all.Does this affect my sproc?

Comment: @Solarflare here is my tabke defination

CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by changing whole database, table and columns to utf8mb4_unicode_ci